# How can I get JSON from request?

Tags: python, json, django

How can I get JSON from request?I wrote codes,

```
@csrf_exempt
def get_json(request):
    print(request)
    return HttpResponse('<h1>OK</h1>')
```

I post data to POSTMAN like
[image]

but

print(request) print out
WSGIRequest: POST '/app/get_json'. 
 I wanna get json in this part.So I wrote

```
print(request.text)
```

but error happens.Why can't I get it?I think request has json data,but is it wrong?How can I do it?

Comment: What is the error, you are getting ?

Comment: It's hard to know your setup from your question. What do you get from `print(request.POST)`?

Comment: @roganjosh print(request.POST) print out QueryDict: {}  .

Comment: @BijoyWhen I wrote print(request.text),  'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'text' error happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`The raw HTTP request body as a byte string`. So use `request.body` to get all the raw body datas and later convert to json.

```
json_body = json.loads(request.body)
```

Comment: Before Python 3.6 you've got to do [`request.body.decode('utf-8')`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55162221/52499) or something.