# TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes' - Python3.x

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I know that there is a lot of questions abut this but no one solved my problem.

I did a simple program which has a "Contact" option. When you choose this option, the program gets the info of the user using [this site](http://freegeoip.net/json/) and add this info in a `mailto:` link.

If I run the program using Python's IDLE or CMD, it works fine. But if I transform it to a `.exe` file using http://pytoexe.com, it does not work. When I opened the `.exe` using a `.bat` file, adding the command `&pause` to see why it's not working, I get this error:

```
C:\Users\Fernando\Downloads>main-GitHub.exe   & pause
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main-GitHub.py", line 9, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
File "c:\Python34\lib\sitepackages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
File "additionalmodules\contact.py", line 21, in <module>
info = load(urllib.request.urlopen('http://freegeoip.net/json/'))
File "json\__init__.py", line 268, in load
File "json\__init__.py", line 312, in loads
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'
```

> TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'

You can see the code at GitHub [here](https://github.com/feRpicoral/Biologia/blob/master/main/modules/contact.py).

If you open the [site](http://freegeoip.net/json/) that I'm using to get the user info, you will see that it's a dictionary, so I don't have idea why that is not working.

The most strange thing is that the program works usgin Python Shell or Windows CMD but as a stand alone program, it does not work.

If you want to try the `.exe` click [here](https://mega.nz/#!2cBC3RbK!xAeSSQFHbb_FaH-xOiLVQVme-T3kZ2LLnJ33bY9l_4U) (this is download link to the `.exe`. Your computer will say that it's virus because it was converted from Python using that site that I said before. If you don't trust me and think that it's a virus, convert yourself downloading the files ate [GitHub](https://github.com/feRpicoral/Biologia) and using [this site](http://pytoexe.com) to convert.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Can't you refrain from asking for two completely unrelated things in each question? It is not as it they were charging you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python3 retrieving 'data' from a source returns bytes instead of a string. So you have to decode it

Try:

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://freegeoip.net/json/')
info = load(response.decode('utf-8'))
```

Beyond that, I would strongly suggest using requests instead of urllib.

It tends to be a bunch more intuitive.

```
import requests # 'pip3 install requests --user' beforehand to install it
response = requests.get('http://freegeoip.net/json/')
response.json() # Fully parsed and loaded as a Dict/JSON Object
```

Also if that doesn't work, then there is some other alternatives, per a similar question on Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42683478/typeerror-the-json-object-must-be-str-not-bytes).

Alternatives [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42683500/3095971)

Use `load` on the text, the `response.json()` should be a Dict if all went right with parsing and if the server returned the right headers.

Link to `requests` docs [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)