# Difference between url.json() and json.loads()

Tags: python, json

I have written the following code to read sample JSON data from url,

```
HEADER = {"content-type": "application/josn"}

session = requests.Session()
session.verify = True
session.headers = HEADER

output = session.request("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", timeout=30)
```

If I print `output` I get,

`<Response [200]>`

If I do,

```
output = session.request("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", timeout=30).json()
```

I get actual `json` content,

```
{u'completed': False, u'userId': 1, u'id': 1, u'title': u'delectus aut autem'}
```

But when I do,

```
output = session.request("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", timeout=30)
print(json.loads(output))
```

I get,

```
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Can someone please give an example to me when should I use `.json()` and when `json.loads()`?

Comment: Possible  dupe: [TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42683478/674039)

Comment: A bit irrelevant to the question at hand, but your `HEADER` declaration has a typo: `application/josn` should be `application/json`.

Comment: can someone please tell me why am I down voted ? i can add more details if needed, but please leave a comment at least.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `.json` is just a shortcut of `json.loads()` when the response is a json.

`print(json.loads(output))`

is not working because you need to get the body of the request, i think it is

`print(json.loads(output.text))`

Comment: This is correct - `output` in the second example in the OP [returns a `Response`-type object](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/?highlight=.request#requests.request), which is not a datatype `json.loads()` accepts as the `s` argument. In fact, the only accepted datatype is `str` of unicode ([source](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads)).

Comment: thank you, how does `.json()` automatically gets the `output.text`?

Comment: @MaverickD because is a method of the response object