# Why does this python code give "TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'" on one machine but not another

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I have a [small public repo](https://github.com/joereddington/vision) with the following python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
import os

def get_json_from_url(url):
    config = json.loads(open(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))+'/config.json').read())
    token = config['token']
    request = Request(url)
    request.add_header('Authorization', 'token %s' % token)
    request.add_header('Accept', "application/vnd.github.inertia-preview+json" )
    response = urlopen(request)
    return json.loads(response.read())

def process_cards(pri,url, tag=""):
   cards= get_json_from_url(url)
   for card in cards: 
       payload=""
       if card['note']:
            payload="map project:"+ card['note']
       else:
            payload="Work on: "+ card['content_url']
       print("({}) {} {}".format(pri,payload,tag))


def process_project_board(url,tag=""):
   board= get_json_from_url(url)
   columns_url= board["columns_url"]
   columns= get_json_from_url(columns_url)
   priorities=['*', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E']
   for x in columns:
      process_cards(priorities.pop(0),x['cards_url'],tag)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   process_project_board("https://api.github.com/projects/1613733","+EQT")
   process_project_board("https://api.github.com/projects/1659667","+PersonalProjects")
```

It works perfectly from my desktop when I run it with

`python3 vision.py`

but when I clone it on a server, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vision.py", line 37, in <module>
    process_project_board("https://api.github.com/projects/1613733","+EQT")
  File "vision.py", line 29, in process_project_board
    board= get_json_from_url(url)
  File "vision.py", line 15, in get_json_from_url
    return json.loads(response.read())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 312, in loads
    s.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'
```

What is causing the difference between behaviours?  There are no missing library errors- the config.json file (where my Github Token is) is identical, and I've never had a similar problem moving things to the server...

Comment: Is the Python version on your server lower than 3.6 ?

Comment: related: [TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42683478/typeerror-the-json-object-must-be-str-not-bytes) - Many times searching with an error message is fruitful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42683478/typeerror-the-json-object-must-be-str-not-bytes)

Comment: @GerardRozsavolgyi ah! it's 3.4! and this https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#json gives me the rest of the answer.  Would you like to write it up yourself for the points?

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/python` should be running Python 2, unless you run it like `python3 yourfile.py`. If you want Python 3, change the shebang to `#!/usr/bin/python3`.

Comment: @Joe. Wrote the answer as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be using a Python version lower than 3.6 on your server and JSON doesn't behave like expected. Upgrade your Python version or use a virualenv so you can use the same code on your Desktop and Server